# Change Blazor Radzen Chart Annotation styling?

Tags: .net, blazor, radzen

Can we change the styling of the fonts of `RadzenSeriesAnnotation`?

I tried to use `style` directly on `RadzenSeriesAnnotation` but it does not have the property matching the name `stlye`.

I also want to change the color of the fonts.

I am able to change the font size by adding `style="font-size:40px;"` to `RadzenChart`.

```
        <RadzenChart style="color:white;width:100%; height:100%;font-size:40px;">
            <RadzenDonutSeries Data="@datas" CategoryProperty="Name" ValueProperty="Value">
                <ChildContent>
                    @for(int i=0;i<datas.Count();i++)
                    {
                        var ii = i;
                        <RadzenSeriesAnnotation Visible=true TItem="Pie" Data="@datas[ii]" OffsetX="50" Text="@annotations[ii]"/>                    
                    }
                </ChildContent>
                <TitleTemplate>
                    <div class="rz-donut-content">
                        <div>Donut Chart</div>                             
                    </div>
                </TitleTemplate>
            </RadzenDonutSeries>
            <RadzenLegend Visible="true" />
        </RadzenChart>
```

Thanks!